# New version of Math

Tags: lateral-thinking

This is a question I found in a book, let's see who can puzzle this out:

> How is 7 half of 12?

Comment: @Will oh, sorry. I didn't find that when I was looking for it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it is:

> XII is 12, but VII (XII cut in half) is 7

Comment: Wow, I honestly wasn't expecting a correct answer so soon, less than a minute after I posted it haha. Good job.

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as the correct answer!

Comment: @Yllrauei I would've marked it right away, but I'm required to wait before I mark it as the site won't let me until the question is 15 minutes old.

Answer (score 6):

If you

> Cut `XII` (12 in Roman numerals) in half along the horizontal, you get `VII` (7)

Comment: I like that using the `code` font invalidates this riddle, as cutting `XII` in this font in half does not, in fact produce `VII`, but rather `VTT`

Comment: @question-asker I didn't meant to nitpick at all.  I apologize if that's how it came out.  I was mostly amused that the answer to the riddle (or rather, whether or not it *has* an answer) depends on what font one uses.  Perhaps I should have included a ":-)" in my original comment. :-)

Comment: @PaulL OK! (PS - don't know why your comment ended up being addressed to dcfyj, but I got a notification anyway.)

Comment: because I'm dumb and didn't realize your name actually was `question_asker`, and thought SE was telling me the asker of the question is the one who left the comment.  I corrected it when I realized my mistake.

Comment: @PaulL Ha! That's totally understandable!